# special case of von Neumann's minimax theorem

Tags: game-theory

The minimax theorem of von Neumann says that for any payoff matrix $A$, we have
\begin{equation}
\max_x \min_y x^T A y = \min_y \max_x x^T A y.
\end{equation}
In the above, $x$ and $y$ are probability distributions.
In the special case when $A$ satisfies:
$$\max_i \min_j A_{ij} = \min_j \max_i A_{i,j} (=A_{\bar{i},\bar{j}}),$$
the maximizing distribution $x$ and the minimizing $y$ in von Neumann's equality above is simply
$x = e_{\bar{i}}$ and $y = e_{\bar{j}}$. (The Nash equilibrium is attained by pure strategies for both players.)

In a yet more (?) specific case when $A$ has a dominant column (or a dominant row), i.e. there exists a $\bar{j}$ so that
$$A_{i,\bar{j}} \leq A_{i,j}, \;\;\; \forall i, \; \forall j,$$
it is quite easy to show that $A$ satisfies the second equality above.

Question: Does the second equality imply the existence of a dominant row or column?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by a dominant column: all entries are greater than? all entries are greater or equal than but at least one entry is greater than? all entries are greater or equal than?

Comment: $A$ has a dominant column if there is a $\bar{j}$ so that
$$A_{i,\bar{j}} \leq A_{i,j}, \;\;\; \forall i, \; \forall j.$$ This means the column player must pursue the pure strategy $\bar{j}$ in order to minimize her loss, regardless of what the row player does. Similarly, $A$ is said to have dominant row if there is a $\bar{i}$ so that
$$A_{\bar{i},j} \geq A_{i,j}, \;\;\; \forall i, \; \forall j.$$